# Download a S3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular2-routing

Im building a webapp using AWS S3.

**Question:** How can I download a file from S3 and save the file in the users Downloads folder?

My code so far:

```
this.getS3().getObject({Bucket:bucket_name, Key:keys},
      function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Error!")
        } else {
          // How to save 'data' file in Download folder?
        }
      });
```

Comment: Did you try [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/requests-using-stream-objects.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i am doing in .NET using the AWS SDK for .Net

```
public class AmazonS3
    {
        //Local varaibles to get the accesskey and secretkey
        private readonly string accessKey;
        private readonly string secretKey;
        private RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint;
        AmazonS3Client client = null;
        TransferUtility utility = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Class Constructor for getting the accesskey and secretkey for the Amazon S3 bucket
        /// </summary>
        public AmazonS3Operations()
        {
            //get the accesskey and secretkey from the web.config

            accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSS3AccessKey"];
            secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSS3SecretKey"];
            regionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSS3RegionEndPoint"]);

            //Initialize the connection here and use it every where in a singleton model
            client = GetS3ClientConnection();
        }

public byte[] GetFileObject(string filePath, string fileNameInS3, out string strContentType)
        {
            byte[] data = null;

            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = filePath;
            request.Key = fileNameInS3;

            //get the object response here
            GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(ms);
                data = ms.ToArray();
            }
            //get the Mimetype here                
            strContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileNameInS3);
            return data;

        }

}
```

Pass your parameters to the method `GetFileObject` which returns the `byte[]` array in response. Create the respective file with the respective name and MIME type in the users download folder.

Refer here for doing the same with Java : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

There are other AWS documents available online too for other languages.